# in `>': comparison of Fixnum with nil failed (ArgumentError) Roman Numeral converter in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am new to Ruby and I am trying to write a program which convert Roman numerals to numbers.

This is what I did so far:

```
roman_numbers = {"M" => 1000, "D" => 500, "C" => 100, "L" => 50, "X" => 10, "V" => 5, "I" => 1}
number_by_user = "MCMXCIX"
singlenum = number_by_user.split(//).reverse!

l = singlenum.length
result =0


result = roman_numbers[singlenum[0]]
puts result
for i in 0..l-1
  if roman_numbers.key?(singlenum[i])
    **if (roman_numbers[singlenum[i]] > roman_numbers[singlenum[i+1]])** #gives error
      result = result - roman_numbers[singlenum[i+1]]
    elsif (roman_numbers[singlenum[i]]== roman_numbers[singlenum[i+1]] || **roman_numbers[singlenum[i]] < roman_numbers[singlenum[i+1]])** #gives error
      result = result + roman_numbers[singlenum[i+1]]
    end
    puts roman_numbers[singlenum[i]]
  else
    puts "One of the values are not roman"
    break
  end  
end
puts "The number is: " , result
```

but it gives me the following error (see the line with comment):

```
:in `>': comparison of Fixnum with nil failed (ArgumentError)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an off-by-one error.  Arrays are 0 indexed.  Your `singlenum.length` in this case is 7, but in your for loop, you go up to 6, then try to reference `singlenum[7]` to compare to `singlenum[6]`.  `singlenum[7]` is `nil`, so it doesn't understand the < operator.

Comment: thanks, I added a condition if roman_numbers.key?(singlenum[i]) && i < l-1 and it works now

Answer (score 4):

Marc did a good job of explaining where the error was in your code. However, such an error should never have occurred in the first place, since in Ruby, all collections already know how to iterate over themselves: *you* don't have to do that, so you can never even *make* such a mistake!

Here's an example of how one might implement the same algorithm in more idiomatic Ruby:

```
numerals = {
  'M' => 1000,
  'D' =>  500,
  'C' =>  100,
  'L' =>   50,
  'X' =>   10,
  'V' =>    5,
  'I' =>    1
}

num = 'MCMXCIX'

(num.chars.map(&numerals.method(:[])) << 0).each_cons(2).inject(0) {|a, (n1, n2)|
  if n1 < n2 then a - n1 else a + n1 end
}
```

See? No loops. No indices. You cannot make an off-by-one error even if you *tried*!

Bonus: *actually*, the above snippet *does* contain a piece of code to prevent an off-by-one error, albeit one at a much higher semantic level. Can you find it?

Comment: Cute :-) Nitpicking: I think that `{|x| numerals[x]}` is clearer and more usual.

Comment: @Marc-AndréLafortune: My bias for point-free style is showing again :-)

Comment: Just figured out a way to DRY this up, but that's not just going too far, that's pretty damn *nuts*: `a.send(if n1 < n2 then :- else :+ end, n1)` :-)

Comment: Actually, you could do `a + n1 * (n1 <=> n2)`